# Ad Hoc deployment fails when shipping Default.png images

Tags: ios, code-signing, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution, default.png

I'm an experiencing an issue where I can't install an Ad Hoc version of my application via TestFlight. The application downloads, but at the installation step it shows something like "YourApp can't be installed", with the following messages appearing on the console:

```
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620393
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.2wYy1J/foo_extracted/Payload/PocketCASbeta.app
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[4764] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 handle_install: API failed
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
Sep 17 16:08:24 unknown installd[4767] <Error>: 00381000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

`codesign --verify` doesn't return any errors, and I have double-checked that I'm using the correct Ad Hoc provisioning profile (`codesign --display -vvvv` confirms this).

However, as soon as I remove all the Default.png images from the application, the install works and the application can be run afterwards. The IPA has a size of about 10 MB without and 15 MB with all Default.png images.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the same error will appear with iTunes distribution, too...

Comment: sorry the last ten posts about test flight were that it worked without it, so I got carried away I guess.

Comment: I'll have to try that for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683464/testflight-fails-to-install-app-and-cannot-delete-partially-installed-app

Comment: Out of curiosity, are/were you using Xcode and iOS 6 beta/GM anywhere along this process?

Comment: Yes, they were. But no change with Xcode 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that upgrading to Xcode 4.5.1 has fixed the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the IPA direct to your device via Xcode?

Connect device.

Open Xcode Organizer / Devices Tab / Select your device / Applications.

Click the + (add) button at the bottom left, select your app.

If this install fails as well, I suspect there's something up with your Default.png image. If you are scripting image conversion, it's worth mentioning that I've had lots of issues in the past using the *sips* command-line utility creating png images that Apple doesn't like, so I've stopped using that. I now use ImageMagick instead and have not had any trouble since.

Comment: Installing via Xcode also fails, with the error message "A valid code signing identity could not be found". But now installing even fails when the Default.png images are removed... But I'll keep the Default.png stuff in mind - I indeed recompressed them using ImageAlpha.

Comment: Never mind that "no install works", I forgot to add my new testing device to the provisioning profile...